# when does asp:datapager control comes in handy?

Tags: asp.net, controls, datapager

Hai guys,
  I really want to know ,

1. when does datapager control comes handy in asp.net?
2. List of controls that uses datapager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataPager control is used with the new ListView control. By factoring it out of the main databinding control, you can position it wherever you want - which lets you be a little more creative. Check out this 10-part series from Scott Mitchell which includes details on its usage with the ListView:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210125144848/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021308-1.aspx

You can also use it to improve your SEO:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211029044137/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/010610-1.aspx

There are a few issues to look out for:

http://leedumond.com/blog/resetting-the-page-index-in-a-listview/